# Is it possible to make a function pointer with parameters in C++

Tags: c++, functor

I'm trying to capture a function pointer to hand to a functor and I don't understand why I can't.

Functor Class:

```
template <class C>
class MyFunctor : public BaseFunctor {
  public:
    typedef long (C::*t_callback)(const long, const char *);

    MyFunctor (void) : BaseFunctor(), obj(NULL), callback(NULL) {}
    virtual long operator() (const long a, const char *b) {
        if ( obj && callback ) {
            (obj->*callback)(a,b);
        }
    }

    C *obj;
    t_callback callback;
};
```

Elsewhere in the code:

The function signature is `long C::Func (const long, const char *)`

```
MyFunctor funky;
funky.obj = this;
funky.callback = Func;
```

Then I get the error:

`... function call missing argument list; ...`

Why does this not work?

**EDIT:** In working through the suggestions below, I came across a simple solution to make my particular implementation work.

`funky.callback = &C::Func;`

Comment: any reason you don't want to use std function

Comment: I am unaware of this feature. I have no aversion to anything in the STL. Can you please list an example as an answer, so I may accept it? Also, could you go into further detail as to why C++ cannot handle parameters and the necessity of std::function?

Comment: Alright didn't really get what you were trying to do but I gave an example of how it works instead of function pointers

Comment: +1 to aaronman's answer. However in regards to your error it looks like you're missing an extra set of parentheses after the `operator` keyword. It should be `virtual long operator() (const long a, const char *b)`

Comment: @LachlanEaston Yes you're correct. I've fixed it, it is correct in my real code. Thank you for double checking!

Comment: try (obj->*callback(a,b));

Comment: `MyFunctor funky;` won't work because the template argument `C` to `MyFunctor` is missing.

Comment: member function pointer is an entire different beast than a function pointer. For example, member function pointer have different size depend on the class and compiler. Seems like you want to store a delegate to a object member function, you can use `std::function` or if you care about performance, look up C++ fast delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do from your code but two C++ features that are much easier to use than function pointers are [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) here's an example of using `std::function` from the site.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;
};

void print_num(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

struct PrintNum {
    void operator()(int i) const
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    // store a free function
    std::function<void(int)> f_display = print_num;
    f_display(-9);

    // store a lambda
    std::function<void()> f_display_42 = []() { print_num(42); };
    f_display_42();

    // store the result of a call to std::bind
    std::function<void()> f_display_31337 = std::bind(print_num, 31337);
    f_display_31337();

    // store a call to a member function
    std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add;
    Foo foo(314159);
    f_add_display(foo, 1);

    // store a call to a function object
    std::function<void(int)> f_display_obj = PrintNum();
    f_display_obj(18);
}
```

This is the function pointer in your code:

```
typedef long (C::*t_callback)(const long, const char *);
```

To make this an `std::funciton` do:

`std::function<long(const long,const char*)> t_callback = something`;

Comment: Can you explain more as to why std::function is necessary, and why this can't be achieved in plain C++ syntax?

Comment: I tried to implement "// store a call to a function object", but I got the same error as I was getting before.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a function with signature `unsigned long Func (const long, const char *)` to a variable of type `long (C::*)(const long, const char *)` because

1. One returns `unsigned long` and the other returns `long`.
2. One is a pointer-to-member, the other is the name of a non-member "free" function.

If you want `Func` to simply be called without a `C` object, then you need to remove `C::` from `t_callback` . If `Func` is actually a member function and your signature is not copied faithfully in the question (**do not paraphrase code!!**), you must use the `::` operator when forming a pointer-to-member value, as in `&ThisClass::Func`.

The peculiar error you see is due to overload resolution being performed on the name. The compiler sees you have something of that name, but it's reporting that none of the things with that name (there could potentially be many) work in the given expression.

---

As others have mentioned, this isn't something you should actually use in a project. This kind of functionality is covered by `std::function` and `std::bind`, which are available even in C++03 using the standardized TR1 library, so doing it yourself is best kept to a self-contained exercise.

Without writing any custom code, you can do

```
std::function< long( long, char * ) > funky = std::bind( &MyClass::Func, this );
```

This gets a pointer-to-member to the `Func` method, attaches the current `this` pointer to it, then creates an indirect-call wrapper around it all which is valid for the lifetime of `this`.

```
funky( 3, "hello" );
```

To avoid the indirect call, use `auto` to avoid declaring a `std::function`. You will get an object of a one-off type. (You can't assign another function to it.)

```
auto funky = std::bind( &MyClass::Func, this );
```

Comment: #1 is right, but only because I left a typo in my "whitewashed" example.

Comment: #2 is more on target, and I believe this is the answer to my original question.

Comment: I should actually give you the checkmark for diagnosing my actual problem. However, as you stated, my method is best left as a personal exercise, and the appropriate way to achieve what I am actually trying to do is through std::function, so I'm giving you a +1 and @aaronman the check, so others with a similar problem as mine will see his answer first. Thanks!

Comment: @Zak Actually on second thought `std::bind` would be a better fit here than `std::function`, and they can be combined if necessary.

Comment: What header is `auto` under?

Comment: @Zak It's part of C++11. You need a fairly recent compiler, and pass a flag that usually looks something like `-std=c++11`.

Comment: I really liked the `std::function<long(long,char*)> funky = std::bind(&MyClass::Func, this)`, but it doesn't want to compile. Are there any typos in there, or any other ideas?

Comment: @Zak Please post a complete, compilable sample in your question. (I don't think there's a need for a new question here.)